# Error rendering Jinja template for Airflow task using BigQueryOperator with SQL file containing template fields

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x, google-cloud-storage

I'm encountering an issue with an Airflow DAG task utilizing the BigQueryOperator. The task involves executing a SQL file (cast.sql) stored at "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/movies/sql/RRR/", and I'm passing parameters to the SQL file using the params argument in the BigQueryOperator.

```
sql_path = "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/movies/sql/RRR/cast.sql"

stage_latest_parameters = {
    "project_id": project_id,
    "dataset_name": dataset_name,
    "date": raw_latest_date,
    "source_table": source,
    "dest_table": dest
}

sql_with_parameters_task = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='sql_with_parameters_task',
    sql=sql_path,
    params=stage_latest_parameters,
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    dag=dag
)
```

ERROR:

```
 Exception rendering Jinja template for task 'sql_with_parameters_task', field 'sql'. 
 Template: '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/movies/sql/RRR/cast.sql'
  ...
 jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /home/airflow/gcs/dags/movies/sql/RRR/cast.sql
```

QUERY:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `{project_id}.{dataset_name}.{dest_table}` 
  AS
  SELECT *, {date} AS date
  FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_name}.{source_table}`
```

Here, I don't need to use any templates. I just need to run the query by passing necessary parameters that are sitting inside a GCS bucket. What was I doing wrong? Appreciate your Help.